# Вывод HTML5 через XSLTProcessor::transformToXML()

Tags: php, xml, html5, xslt

Шаблонизатор предполагает, что шаблон сайта хранится в виде XSLT, а данные передаются в виде сгенерированного XML:

```
$viewFile = /*...*/'.xsl';

$this->xml = new DomDocument();
$this->xml->appendChild($this->xml->createElement('page'));

$xsl = new DomDocument();
$xsl->load($viewFile);
$proc = new XSLTProcessor();
$proc->importStylesheet($xsl);
return $proc->transformToXML($this->xml);
```

на выходе генерируется:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Как сделать так, чтобы выводился стандартный заголовок HTML5

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
```

, не прибегая к str_replace() перед return и подобным конструкциям?